# formatting the return in python - print out different types of values

Tags: python

I have the following code

```
$ipython
> import csv
> with open('q1_4.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
      reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter = ' ', quotechar = '|')
      for row in reader:
          print [tuple(row)]
```

In each row, I have four values, each of which is a string, a number, a number and a number. How could I print out "string", num, num, num for each row, instead of "string", "string", "string", "string"?

**UPDATED**
I have this modification based on the comments below:

```
import csv
from itertools import chain

result = []
with open("q1_4.csv", "rb") as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter = ",", quotechar = "|")
    for row in reader:
        result.append(tuple(chain([row[0]], map(float, row[1:4]))))
        print result
```

As I am interested in getting the tuple results into a list, I have result = [] and the following modifications. However, this gives me as many replicates as the number of row in my dataset. How could this be improved? Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If formatting is all you are concerned about

```
with open('q1_4.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter = ' ', quotechar = '|')
    for row in reader:
        print '"{}", {}, {}, {}'.format(*row)
```

Test:

```
>>> row = ["string", "1", "2", "3"]
>>> print '"{}", {}, {}, {}'.format(*row)
"string", 1, 2, 3
```

**Update** per your request in the comments. Here are several options you can use to return a tuple

```
return (row[0],) + tuple(int(n) for n in row[1:])  # Python 2 and 3
return (row[0],) + tuple(map(int, row[1:]))  # Python 2 and 3
return tuple(chain([row[0]], map(int, row[1:]))) # Python 2 and 3; requires importing `chain` from `itertools`
```

Though I prefer Python 3 here:

```
return (row[0], *map(int, row[1:]))  # Python 3 only
```

If you want to return a list of tuples, take any of that constructs (I'll pick the third one for brevity) and do:

```
return [(row[0], *map(int, row[1:])) for row in reader]
```

**NOTE** You can only return from a function, so you'll have to wrap it all into a function.

Comment: Thank you. This works. What if I want something further, such as returning a list of tuples of the results? Sorry I did not make it completely clear in my question.

Comment: Thank you for such a comprehensive answer. this is really cool. I had float numbers, so I changed 'int' to 'float', and it works as well. In order to put all the tuple results in a list, I did this `result = []
with open("q1_4.csv", "rb") as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter = ",", quotechar = "|")
    for row in reader:
        result.append(tuple(chain([row[0]], map(float, row[1:]))))
        print result' Nevertheless, it gives me too much - too many replicates...They are not from your code but my modification.

Comment: @Hsun-YiHsieh what do you mean by "too many replicates". You print your entire csv. If you don't want to do it, make a subset.

Comment: When it appends, it seems appends for as many times as the number of the rows. I edited my question code.

Comment: @Hsun-YiHsieh yes it appends all the rows you have? If that's not the behaviour you want, describe your desired behaviour.

Comment: Very cool. Thank you for the answer. Everything works so well except of "return". I changed it to "print" and it gave me all I need!